# Find the values of n such that y(t) = t^n is a solution of the equation t^2 - 6y = 0

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

In the question above, I tried to use Cauchy-Euler Equation to find a solution, then somehow solving for n. But the solution y(t)=t^n is confusing.
Can anyone help and give a solution to part A and B, and I will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

$$y=t^n\implies y''=n (n-1)t^{n-2} $$

$$t^2y''-6y=(n (n-1)-6)t^n$$

we have a solution if $$n(n-1)=6$$
which gives
$$n=3 \;\;\;\text {or}\;\;\; n=-2$$

Yes You can finish.